# Update multiple tables in single query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to update multiple tables using single pgsql query, I have searched on this, but i did'nt find the solution. Tell me if it is possible to do that above case.

Answer (score 0):

You question is rather vague, but the answer is "yes".  You an use `update` in CTEs:

```
with u1 as (
      update . . .
     ),
     u2 as (
      update . . .
     )
update . . .;
```

This is Postgres-specific syntax and you can use `returning` to return columns or rows of interest from each update.  You can read about data-modifying CTEs in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).